# Hyper HTTP20Push()

Tags: python, http2

I am using the python module, "Hyper". I am trying to make a request to the server wherein I can define the scheme, path, etc, which are used by the HTTP 2.0 protocol. The class to do this is defined as:

```
class hyper.HTTP20Push(request_headers, stream)
```

However, if I try something like this:

```
HTTP20Push('scheme': 'test', conn)
```

I get syntax errors. Does this protocol use dicts or strings? If I do it like this:

```
HTTP20Push('scheme=test', conn)
```

It tells me that it is not supposed to be a string, but an integer.

Comment: I don't know about Hyper, but I think you should check two things: first, look in the Python docs how to pass arguments to a function. And then check how HTTP/2 works. I think that HTTP20Push, by the name of it, should be used on a server application to push resources to a client, not in a client.

Comment: I don't know what kind of parameters the function takes, though. Anyway, I probably won't end up using it because I need a client-side version of this to send these headers to the server.

Comment: If you want a neat way to send headers to an HTTP/2 server, you can try curl --http2 -H ...  saves you some coding.

Comment: I can't get cURL's http2 option, though. It tells me I'm using an unsupported protocol. I'm on windows

Comment: You should get a recent version of cURL. 7.43 or upwards. And I already regard you as a pretty tough guy for managing to use Python and cURL together in Windows... that would take *me* not less than three hours....

Comment: I'm using curl 7.46.0 but --http2 or --http2.0 returns unknown protocol

Comment: You need to link it against nghttp2. Where did you download curl from? Did you try http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win64 ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to install nghttp2 in windows, because when I download it I get a makefile.

Comment: The Windows curl binaries from https://bintray.com/vszakats/generic/ should be http2 enabled.